# Unexpected end of input error with chrome.tabs.query

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this and have had no luck. I've included the error and most of the context around the block in question.

```
var successURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html';
var userFirstName = ''
var userEmail = ''

function onFacebookLogin(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
      for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].url.indexOf(successURL) !== -1) {
          var params = tabs[i].url.split('#')[1];
          var accessToken = params.split('&')[0];
          accessToken = accessToken.split('=')[1];
          localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
          chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
          console.log(accessToken);
          pullSecurityToken();
          findFacebookName();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onFacebookLogin);

function pullSecurityToken(){
  var pointUrl = "localhost:3000/api/v1/retrieve_token_for/" + localStorage.accessToken + "/" + localStorage.securityToken;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", pointUrl, true);
  alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}

var response = ''
function findFacebookName(){
  if (localStorage.accessToken) {
    var graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + localStorage.accessToken;
    console.log(graphUrl);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", graphUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr.status == '401'){
          alert("Security Token Invalid, please check and try again.");
        }
        response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        userFirstName = response.first_name
        userEmail = response.email
        console.log(response);
      }    
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at onFacebookLogin (chrome-extension://dapeikoncjikfbmjnpfhemaifpmmgibg/background.js:7:17)
```

Comment: There is no syntax error in your code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code doesn't expose the problem the OP described.

Comment: I took the code and pasted it into the console and no error was thrown. Maybe the error is thrown somewhere in response to executing the code.

Comment: @JustusDannyEapen There definitely isn't. Even if there were, this would be off-topic for Stack Overflow. This site isn't for helping you find your typos.

Comment: Then explain the error I'm getting?

Comment: @JustusDannyEapen Since this code doesn't do anything on its own, I have to assume it's part of a larger file, and that the error shows up in that context. We can't explain the error, since we can't *see* the error, so it's likely you haven't included the *cause* of the error.

Comment: Wowowowow this is why I love this community

Comment: I assume the response you get from one of the Ajax calls (probably in `pullSecurityToken`), is not valid. Is `alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));` ever executed? If not, the response is probably not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use a synchronous request, you still need to [`send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#send()) it. So add an `xhr.send();` after the `xhr.open` inside `pullSecurityToken`.

As Felix Kling points out in the comments, the lack of `send` will directly cause your error, because the `responseText` property is still an empty string and such a string is not valid JSON whereas `""` would be valid JSON.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. `JSON.parse("") -> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`